# Text alignment between curly braces

Tags: braces, mathjax

I am trying to rewrite an equation that looks like this:

[image]

The latex code I have written so far is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\[f(x,\alpha,x_m) = \biggl\{ \frac {\alpha x_m^\alpha} {x_i^{\alpha + 1}},  x \ge x_m \]

\end{document}
```

Which gives the following compilation:
[image]

How do I align the rest of the values I need as shown in the first pic.

Comment: You need `cases` environment for that: `\[
    f(x,\alpha,x_m) =
    \begin{cases}
        \frac {\alpha x_m^\alpha} {x_i^{\alpha + 1}}, & x \ge x_m  \\
        0,& x < m
    \end{cases}
\]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `cases` environment if the material to the right of the tall curly brace should be typeset in text-style math mode, and a `dcases` environment if the material should be typeset in display-style math mode.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools} % for 'dcases' environment
\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
f(x,\alpha,x_m) &=  
\begin{cases} 
\frac {\alpha x_m^\alpha} {x_i^{\alpha + 1}} & \text{if $x\ge x_m$} \\
0 & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases} \\[2ex]
f(x,\alpha,x_m) &=  
\begin{dcases} 
\frac {\alpha x_m^\alpha} {x_i^{\alpha + 1}} & \text{if $x\ge x_m$} \\
0 & \text{otherwise}
\end{dcases}
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```